# Create a feature to add a custom permission level and groups

Tags: permissions, feature-stapling

Need to automate the custom permission level creation and groups.

Please give me some pointers which can guide me to create a feature to add a custom permission level and groups and staple the same with site def

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as writing a feature, I've outlined how to do that with event receivers [here](http://www.thelineberrys.com/default-category/how-to-store-each-sharepoint-site-collection-in-its-own-database---part-3-2.html).

You'll just need to replace the code to add event receivers with your code to add permission levels and groups.  Also, at the bottom of the post I talk about how to staple it to a specific site definition.

Permission levels are called roles in the api.  You will want to create a new [SPRoleDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproledefinition.aspx), configure the name and basepermissions, and then add it to the SPWeb.RoleDefinitions collection.

Groups are called groups in the api.  You will want to call SPWeb.Groups.Add to create a group.

I hope this all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

As Steve suggests, SPRoleDefinition is the way to go together with [SPRoleAssignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproleassignment.aspx). If you are migrating from SharePoint 2003 to SharePoint 2007 your SPRole class would still work but I suggest migrating that part of code to the new classes.